# Запись объектов в файл

Tags: python

На основе структуры классов создать минимум 100 объектов с различными значениями атрибутов и записать все объекты в файл:
запись каждого объекта начинается с новой строки.
Не уверен,что правильно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть функция вставки кода это первое. Второе вы открыли и пишете в fe, а закрываете f

Answer (score 1):

Пусть в файле каджый объект сохраняется в таком виде:

```
<название класса>,<название объекта>,<поле>=<значение>,<поле>=<значение>,...
<название класса>,<название объекта>,<поле>=<значение>,<поле>=<значение>,...
...
```

Таким образом, каждый класс должен сожержать соответствующий метод формирования своего представления в виде строки (в Python2 и 3 немного отличаются и далее есть тонкости).
Далее код,

```
fe = open(...)
samsung = []
# каким-то образом генерируем >= 100 различных объектов, инициализируем их поля и сохраняем в массив samsung

# НЕ забываем про питоновские отступы!
for i in range(0, 100):
    obj_str =  str(samsung[i]) + '\n' # получаем строкое представление объекта
    fe.write(obj_str) # записываем в файл

fe.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# ... с различными значениями атрибутов
# random.randint(a, b)
# Вернуть случайное целое число N такое, что a <= N <= b.

from random import randint

# На основе структуры классов
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a=100, b=500):
        self.value = str(randint(a, b))

# создать минимум 100 объектов с различными значениями атрибутов и записать все объекты в файл: запись каждого объекта начинается с новой строки.
with open("f2.txt", "w") as f:
    for _ in range(100):
        f.write(MyClass(33, 300).value + "\n")
```